# How show product category name in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this schema:

```
Schema::create('product_selected_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory1_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory1_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory2_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory2_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory3_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory3_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory4_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory4_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory5_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory5_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory6_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory6_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory7_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory7_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory8_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory8_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory9_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory9_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');;
        });

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            //$table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->smallInteger('id_delivery_vat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_delivery_vat')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->smallInteger('id_product_vat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_product_vat')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->bigInteger('id_producer')->unsigned();
            //$table->foreign('id_producer')->references('id')->on('product_producers');
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('qr_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('oe_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->char('promo', 1)->default(0);
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('product_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('promo_product_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('product_delivery_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity')->default(0);
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 85)->nullable();
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->integer('level')->default(0);
            //$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            //$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('number')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

Model:

```
class ProductSelectedCategory extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['subcategory1_id', 'parent_subcategory1_id', 'category_id', 'subcategory2_id', 'parent_subcategory2_id', 'subcategory3_id', 'parent_subcategory3_id', 'subcategory4_id', 'parent_subcategory4_id', 'subcategory5_id', 'parent_subcategory5_id', 'subcategory6_id', 'parent_subcategory6_id', 'subcategory7_id', 'parent_subcategory7_id', 'subcategory8_id', 'parent_subcategory8_id', 'subcategory9_id', 'parent_subcategory9_id', 'product_id' ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}

class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'name', 'url_address', 'level', 'parent_id', 'number'];
    public $timestamps = true;
    //protected $table = 'products_category';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategory', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_selected_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'id_delivery_vat', 'id_product_vat', 'id_producer', 'name', 'qr_code', 'oe_code', 'enable', 'promo', 'description', 'product_price', 'promo_product_price', 'product_delivery_price', 'quantity', 'url_address'];
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'id_producer');
    }

    public function producer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductProducer', 'id_producer');
    }

    public function selected_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSelectedCategory');
    }
}
```

I want show product with category name.
category_id = category.id
subcategory1_id = category.id
..... 
etc

In blade I have:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
{{ $product->name }} - {{ $product->selected_categories->first()->parent_subcategory2_id }}, 
@endforeach
```

This return me: product name - 1 (id category) - 3 (id category).

I need name - not ID. How can I change it?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but before trying to return the name, I recommend you to take a step back and study a little more about laravel, php, databases, and etc. That are a lot of mistakes in your code. Your schema and relationships doesn't make sense, you don't need to set `$timestamps` to true, you are calling the wrong relationship to return the name of the category in your blade view, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why you have the product_selected_categories table filled with all these subcategories. You are using the foreign key constraints correctly, but you don't have to set the guard to 'id' in the model since this is always set to the 'id' column if nothing is set.

Also, unless you have other types of categories, I would call the products_categories table just categories.

If you just want a one-to-many relationship with your categories, you can use the build-in functionalities of Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Currently, the database isn't very nice to look at.

Then, if you want the name of a category, just type

```
@foreach($products as $product)
{{ $product->name }} - {{ $product->category->name }}
@endforeach
```

If you want to keep it the way you currently have (which I don't recommend), you can use

```
@foreach($products as $product)
{{ $product->name }} - {{ $product->selected_categories->first()->name}}, 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Th. I try this: {{ $product->selected_categories->first()->name}}- but it's return nothing :(

Comment: Aaaah, I see what went wrong. When you request `selected_categories` you get a `product_selected_categories`, which doesn't have a name. You either have to make the `product_selected_categories` return a category, so you can do `$product->selected_categories->first()->category->name`, or just remove that table and make the product have a category.